# Trouble adjusting background image size to responsive view

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to fit my background image to responsive view,
 but all I have been getting is cropped image.

```css
.container_bg {
background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/qjAvmjN.jpg");
height: 1635px; /*My Image height is 1635 px 
}
```

```html
<div class="container_bg">
A
</div>
```

Now when I switch to "iphone x" view from chrome inspection
Only top left part is shown, How can I adjust the size of background
as per responsive mode. 
I also used `background-size:100% auto` 
It shrinks the image and all my contents goes outside the `DIV`.
Is there a way, or should I make different image size for responsive?

Comment: Please check my answer, this fixes the issue you are facing with your code.

Answer (score 0):

To make your background stretch over, use `background-size` to stretch it which will mean you don't need the `height` and `background-position` will allow you to center the image in the middle of the screen.

```css
.container_bg {
    height: 1635px;
    background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/qjAvmjN.jpg");
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: top center !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_bg">
A
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this. But it stretched the background. Here is the original [Link](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/conceptsam).

Comment: @AnujJoshi I've checked and it doesn't seem to be an issue, have you tried clearing your cache and saved browser files? Try clearing your cache and checking again.

Comment: Did you see it on mobile view? Only the hand part is shown. Compare the background image with and without mobile view on.

Comment: @AnujJoshi Could you try using `background-size: contain;` and seeing if that works?

Comment: I used `background-size: contain;` It repeats the image so used `background-repeat:none;` And it shrinks the image ,Any My DIV contents are outside it. I guess I ll have to change the image size then